# WPF DataGridCheckColumn, check checkbox after selection changed

Tags: wpf, datagrid, checkbox

I have DataGrid like:

```
<DataGrid Name="paragonyDG" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding zaznaczone}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    **<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Zaznacz" Binding="{Binding check}"></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>**
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nazwa paragonu" Binding="{Binding nazwa}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wystawiony przez" Binding="{Binding osoba}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kwota paragonu" Binding="{Binding kwota}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rabat" Binding="{Binding rabat}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data otwarcia" Binding="{Binding dataO}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data zamknięcia" Binding="{Binding dataZ}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Formy płatności" Binding="{Binding formy}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And its bind into class :

```
public class zaznaczone
{
    public bool check { get; set; }
    public int docID { get; set; }
    public string nazwa { get; set; }
    public string osoba { get; set; }
    public decimal kwota { get; set; }
    public decimal rabat { get; set; }
    public string dataO { get; set; }
    public string dataZ { get; set; }
    public string formy { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in datagrid.selectionchanged i'd like to check this checkbox.
I've tried to parse selectedItem.columns[0] to checkbox, but i cannot parse datagridrow to "zaznaczone".
How can i check checkbox?

Comment: Do you use ViewModels, any of MVVM frameworks?

Comment: Well, im actually changing zaznaczone.check as true if row[i] checkbox is checked, implementation like below. zaznaczone class have more public int's and string's with just get;set; methods. Ill edit 1st post and complete whole class implementation and datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `SelectedItem` property of `DataGrid`: `SelectedItem="{Binding zaznaczoneItem}"`. After that you can modify `check` property of `zaznaczoneItem`.

Please note that your `DataContext` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I recommend you to look on [MVVMLight framework](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)